# "back" form button giving XHTML erros

Tags: html

I am trying to validate my pages with "back" form buttons and I keep receiving the below errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

Errors:

Line 54, Column 10: required attribute "action" not specified

Line 56, Column 54: there is no attribute "onClick"
…type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Ba…

Line 56, Column 98: end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
…="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Back">

Line 56, Column 9: start tag was here

Comment: HTML Code: <div id="extendzachad">
  <div align="left">
    
    <form>
      <div align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Back"> 
      </div>
    </form>
    <p align="center"><a href="JJLogo -BIG.jpg"><img src="JJDrivelabel.jpg" alt="jingle Jar label" width="320" height="195" align="right"  /></a></p>
    <div align="center"><span class="style7">Jingle Jar Label    </span>
    </div>
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

Comment: in the future you can put code directly your in post. Just paste it in, select it, then click the code code button identified with a series of binary numbers `101010`. You can also edit your post and add it in later so you don't have to post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Line 54, Column 10: required attribute "action" not specified

Forms need an [action](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-action), the attribute specifies a URL to submit the form data to.

In this case, it sounds like you don't have a form, just a button with some JavaScript hooked up to it. Get rid of the form element.

> Line 56, Column 54: there is no attribute "onClick" …type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Ba…

[XHTML is case sensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2). All attribute values must be lower case. i.e. `onclick`

That said, using [intrinsic event attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) is considered a bad practice. Aim to use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (i.e. start with HTML elements which make sense without JavaScript (and generate the entire element with JS when that is impossible) and bind events using JS. Then put all the JS in an external file and reference it with a src attribute).

> Line 56, Column 98: end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified …="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Back">

[All elements require end tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6). e.g. `<input></input>`, except that input is defined as an empty element and you are almost certainly [serving it with a text/html content-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines), so you need to use [the empty element syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) and end the start tag with a slash instead of having an explicit end tag. i.e. `<input />`

As a final note: Browsers have a back button. Duplicating it is a waste of time and causes confusion as some sites use Back to mean "Forward to where we expect you came here from" and others mean "Use JavaScript to emulate clicking on the browser's back button". The two different meanings sometimes mean that users don't know where the button will actually go, and won't know what effect it will have on their browser history (i.e. how their back and forward buttons will act).

Comment: I upvoted your answer to counteract whoever down-voted you (and because it's a very good answer). I can't see anything wrong with anything you said (or mine answer either, for that matter, which was also down-voted).

Answer (score 0):

`Line 54, Column 10: required attribute "action" not specified`

`<form>` tags require an action attribute, like `<form action="/some/path">`

`Line 56, Column 54: there is no attribute "onClick" …type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" alt="Go Ba…`

All attributes must be in lowercase, like `onclick="whatever"`

`Line 56, Column 98: end tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified …="button"`

All tags must be closed, so change your input to include a closing `/`, like this: `<input type="button" ... alt="Go Back" />`

`Line 56, Column 9: start tag was here`

This is just pointing to where the unclosed tag above started.

Comment: Um, can whoever down-voted this answer and David's answer please explain what we said wrong? Hannah asked why her XHTML validations were failing, and we both answered correctly as far as I can tell. I actually think David's answer is better because it covers everything I said and more (if I was Hannah I would mark his answer accepted), but still neither of us gave any wrong or misleading information. Why the down-votes?